# Modify the handled exception fault message in Apache camel

Tags: exception, apache-camel

In my camel route, I am making a direct-vm call to an existing bundle. In that service, they have handled the exception and setting up some custom fault message. When any exception occurs in that service they are sending fault message like below.

```
{
"errorCode": "400",
"errorMessage": "Unknown error"
}
```

But I need to form my own custom fault message based on the fault message received. But once an exception occurs in second bundle, i am not able to recive the fault message and modify it. below is how my route looks.

```
   <route handleFault="true" streamCache="true" id="route1">
    <from uri="cxfrs://bean://testCxf?synchronous=true"/>
    <log message="The consumer message  ${body}"/> 
      <bean ref="requestValidator" method="validateRequest"/>
      <to uri="direct-vm:retrieveData"/>
      <bean ref="validateResponse" method="validate"/>//need to manipulate  the fault message coming from bundle 2 in this bean.
    <onException>
      <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
      <handled>
        <constant>true</constant>
      </handled>
      <bean ref="faultMapper" method="mapFault"/>
    </onException>
   </route>
```

Below is the existing direct:vm route.

```
<route handleFault="true" streamCache="true" id="route2">
    <from uri="direct-vm:retrieveData"/>
      <bean ref="manipulateData" method"manipulate"/>
        <onException>
          <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
          <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
          </handled>
          <bean ref="faultMapper1" method="mapFault1"/>
        </onException>
    </route>
```

i need to intercept the fault that is mapped in the class faultmapper1, in my route1 after the direct-vm call.How to acheive this?. I will not be allowed to change anything in the existing 2nd bundle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But a better design would have been to do the custom error message handling in a separate route that depending on for example a specific header would generate a custom error message. When a request from your route comes and an error occurs that header would be used and so on. Easier to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research found that this is not possible. To achieve the requirement, I have made the handled constant as false in the second route and added a , block in the first route. So that I can catch the exception thrown and handled it with some custom fault mapping.